# How do I preserve variables in batch scripts when set in "for" loops?

Tags: scripting, batch-file, dos

I need to set my classpath using all of the jars in a particular directory.  Bash does it as follows:

```
CP_DELIMITER=;
for j in "$MY_HOME/javalib/*.jar"; do
    if [ "$CP" ]; then
        CP="$CP$CP_DELIMITER$j"
    else
        CP="$j"
    fi
done
```

But "`for`" works differently in DOS, and essentially sends the command to the shell, but won't preserve the "set" on the variable

```
set CP=./
for %%j in (%MY_HOME%\javalib\*.jar) do (
    set $CP=%CP%;"%%j"
)
```

When you ask for `$CP` outside the for, you only get the last jar file. If you echo inside, you can see that `%%j` does have all of the values.

Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enable **delayed environment variable expansion** with `CMD.EXE /V` and use `!VAR!`:

```
set CP=./
for %%j in (%MY_HOME%\javalib*.jar) do ( set CP=!CP!;"%%j" )
```

Comment: Great, that works, and an alternative to /V on the command line is:
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION